# reference constant inside object freeze in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

What is the correct way to assign myData.firstName in  selectors.page2Data._3txtFamilyName:
Is there a possibility?

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
myData: {
    firstName : 'first',
    lastName : 'last ',
    streetNum : 'number',
},
selectors:{
    page2Data:{

        _3txtFamilyName: function(){ return myData.firstName},
        _4txtgivenName:  function(){this.myData.lastName},
        _5txtAddressStreetNo:  function(){this.myData.streetNum} ,


    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is assign the whole object to a variable and use that variable internally as needed. Then export that variable

```js
const obj = Object.freeze({
  myData: {
    firstName: 'first',

  },
  selectors: {
    page2Data: {
      _3txtFamilyName: function() {
        return obj.myData.firstName
      }


    }
  }
})
//module.exports = obj
console.log(obj.selectors.page2Data._3txtFamilyName())
```

Answer (score 0):

The organization of this object makes it very inconvenient to use the functions. `this` inside those functions will refer to the `page2Data` object not the main parent object. So using `this.myData` will return undefined in those functions.

If you absolutely couldn't change this to a more convenient object you could call the functions using `call()` and pass in the outside object. But it's a pretty ugly way to do it:

```js
let e = Object.freeze({
  myData: {
    firstName: 'first',
  },
  selectors: {
    page2Data: {
      _3txtFamilyName: function() {
        this.myData.firstName = "mark"
      },
    }
  }
});

e.selectors.page2Data._3txtFamilyName.call(e) // pass in explicit value for this
console.log(e.myData)
```

An alternative would be to change `selectors` to a getter function. This would allow you to capture the exterior object in a closure:

```js
let e = Object.freeze({
  myData: {
    firstName: 'first',
  },
  get selectors() {         // getter instead of plain object
    let self = this         // capture this
    return {
      page2Data: {
        _3txtFamilyName: function() {
          self.myData.firstName = "mark"
        },
      }
    }
  }
});

// now you can call it normally
e.selectors.page2Data._3txtFamilyName(e)
console.log(e.myData)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way to do this in your current context would be to do the following,

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    myData: {
        firstName : 'first',
        lastName : 'last ',
        streetNum : 'number',
    },
    selectors:{
        page2Data:{

            _3txtFamilyName: function(){
                return module.exports.myData.firstName
            },
            _4txtgivenName:  function(){
                return module.exports.myData.lastName
            },
            _5txtAddressStreetNo:  function(){
                return module.exports.myData.streetNum
            } ,


        }
    }
});
```